# Why is this drag n drop between listviews failing?

Tags: wpf, listview, .net-5, winui-3

I copied the code from the Xaml Controls Gallery. When I run and drag the listitem, the app closes. If  I  run in debug, F10 doesn't lead me to the part of the code that's breaking. In fact, the app stays open but nothing happens. I'm stumped.

(this is from winui3-preview 4)

`Contact.txt`
https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/Assets/Contacts.txt

`// ListBoxPage.xaml (I know bad naming)`

```
<Page
x:Class="NavTest.ListBoxPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:NavTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:local1="using:Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources>
    <!-- 
        ListViews with grouped items must be bound to a CollectionViewSource, as shown below.
        This CollectionViewSource is defined in the XAML below, but is bound to an ItemsSource in the C#
        code-behind. See the C# code below for more details on how to create/bind to a grouped list. 
    -->

    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ContactsCVS" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>

    <!-- 
        In this example, the ListView's ItemTemplate property is bound to a data template (shown below)
        called ContactListViewTemplate, defined in a Page.Resources section. 
    -->

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContactListViewTemplate" x:DataType="local:Contact">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" x:Phase="1" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="BaseExample"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsCVS.View, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"
        Width="550"
        Height="400"
        CanDragItems="True"
        CanReorderItems="True"
        AllowDrop="True"
        DragItemsStarting="BaseExample_DragItemsStarting"
        DragOver="BaseExample_DragOver"
        Drop="BaseExample_Drop"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:GroupInfoList">
                        <Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
    <ListView
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        x:Name="BaseExample2"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"
        Width="550"
        Height="400"
        CanDragItems="True"
        CanReorderItems="True"
        AllowDrop="True"
        DragItemsStarting="BaseExample2_DragItemsStarting"
        DragOver="BaseExample2_DragOver"
        DragEnter="BaseExample2_DragEnter"
        Drop="BaseExample_Drop"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">

    </ListView>


</Grid>
```

`// ListBoxPage.xaml.cs`

```
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.WebUI;




// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace NavTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class ListBoxPage : Page
    {

        ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts1 = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts2 = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

        public ListBoxPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();           
        }

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // The ItemsSource for the ListView is generated by a method of the Contact class called
            // GetContactsAsync().This method pulls data from an internal data source and creates
            // Contact objects from that data. Those Contact objects are placed in a collection
            // which is returned from the GetContactsAsync() function.

            contacts1 = await Contact.GetContactsAsync();
            contacts2 = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
            BaseExample.ItemsSource = contacts1;
            BaseExample2.ItemsSource = contacts2;

            ContactsCVS.Source = await Contact.GetContactsGroupedAsync();
        }

        private void BaseExample_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Prepare a string with one dragged item per line
            StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Contact item in e.Items)
            {
                if (items.Length > 0) { items.AppendLine(); }
                if (item.ToString() != null)
                {
                    // Append name from contact object onto data string
                    items.Append(item.ToString() + " " + item.Company);
                }
            }
            // Set the content of the DataPackage
            e.Data.SetText(items.ToString());

            e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
        }

        private void BaseExample_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
        }

        private async void BaseExample_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView target = (ListView)sender;

            if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
            {
                DragOperationDeferral def = e.GetDeferral();
                string s = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
                string[] items = s.Split('\n');
                foreach (string item in items)
                {

                    // Create Contact object from string, add to existing target ListView
                    string[] info = item.Split(" ", 3);
                    Contact temp = new Contact(info[0], info[1], info[2]);

                    // Find the insertion index:
                    Windows.Foundation.Point pos = e.GetPosition(target.ItemsPanelRoot);

                    // Find which ListView is the target, find height of first item
                    ListViewItem sampleItem;
                    if (target.Name == "BaseExample")
                    {
                        sampleItem = (ListViewItem)BaseExample2.ContainerFromIndex(0);
                    }
                    // Only other case is target = DragDropListView2
                    else
                    {
                        sampleItem = (ListViewItem)BaseExample.ContainerFromIndex(0);
                    }

                    // Adjust ItemHeight for margins
                    double itemHeight = sampleItem.ActualHeight + sampleItem.Margin.Top + sampleItem.Margin.Bottom;

                    // Find index based on dividing number of items by height of each item
                    int index = Math.Min(target.Items.Count - 1, (int)(pos.Y / itemHeight));

                    // Find the item that we want to drop
                    ListViewItem targetItem = (ListViewItem)target.ContainerFromIndex(index); ;

                    // Figure out if to insert above or below
                    Windows.Foundation.Point positionInItem = e.GetPosition(targetItem);
                    if (positionInItem.Y > itemHeight / 2)
                    {
                        index++;
                    }

                    // Don't go out of bounds
                    index = Math.Min(target.Items.Count, index);

                    // Find correct source list
                    if (target.Name == "BaseExample")
                    {
                        // Find the ItemsSource for the target ListView and insert
                        contacts1.Insert(index, temp);
                        //Go through source list and remove the items that are being moved
                        foreach (Contact contact in BaseExample2.Items)
                        {
                            if (contact.FirstName == temp.FirstName && contact.LastName == temp.LastName && contact.Company == temp.Company)
                            {
                                contacts2.Remove(contact);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (target.Name == "BaseExample2")
                    {
                        contacts2.Insert(index, temp);
                        foreach (Contact contact in BaseExample.Items)
                        {
                            if (contact.FirstName == temp.FirstName && contact.LastName == temp.LastName && contact.Company == temp.Company)
                            {
                                contacts1.Remove(contact);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
                def.Complete();
            }
        }

        private void BaseExample_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // We don't want to show the Move icon
            e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = false;
        }

        private void BaseExample2_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Items.Count == 1)
            {
                // Prepare ListViewItem to be moved
                Contact tmp = (Contact)e.Items[0];

                e.Data.SetText(tmp.FirstName + " " + tmp.LastName + " " + tmp.Company);
                e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
            }
        }

        private void BaseExample2_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
        }

        private async void BaseExample2_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView target = (ListView)sender;

            if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
            {
                DragOperationDeferral def = e.GetDeferral();
                string s = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
                string[] items = s.Split('\n');
                foreach (string item in items)
                {

                    // Create Contact object from string, add to existing target ListView
                    string[] info = item.Split(" ", 3);
                    Contact temp = new Contact(info[0], info[1], info[2]);

                    // Find the insertion index:
                    Windows.Foundation.Point pos = e.GetPosition(target.ItemsPanelRoot);

                    // Find which ListView is the target, find height of first item
                    ListViewItem sampleItem;
                    if (target.Name == "BaseExample")
                    {
                        sampleItem = (ListViewItem)BaseExample2.ContainerFromIndex(0);
                    }
                    // Only other case is target = DragDropListView2
                    else
                    {
                        sampleItem = (ListViewItem)BaseExample.ContainerFromIndex(0);
                    }

                    // Adjust ItemHeight for margins
                    double itemHeight = sampleItem.ActualHeight + sampleItem.Margin.Top + sampleItem.Margin.Bottom;

                    // Find index based on dividing number of items by height of each item
                    int index = Math.Min(target.Items.Count - 1, (int)(pos.Y / itemHeight));

                    // Find the item that we want to drop
                    ListViewItem targetItem = (ListViewItem)target.ContainerFromIndex(index); ;

                    // Figure out if to insert above or below
                    Windows.Foundation.Point positionInItem = e.GetPosition(targetItem);
                    if (positionInItem.Y > itemHeight / 2)
                    {
                        index++;
                    }

                    // Don't go out of bounds
                    index = Math.Min(target.Items.Count, index);

                    // Find correct source list
                    if (target.Name == "BaseExample")
                    {
                        // Find the ItemsSource for the target ListView and insert
                        contacts1.Insert(index, temp);
                        //Go through source list and remove the items that are being moved
                        foreach (Contact contact in BaseExample2.Items)
                        {
                            if (contact.FirstName == temp.FirstName && contact.LastName == temp.LastName && contact.Company == temp.Company)
                            {
                                contacts2.Remove(contact);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (target.Name == "BaseExample2")
                    {
                        contacts2.Insert(index, temp);
                        foreach (Contact contact in BaseExample.Items)
                        {
                            if (contact.FirstName == temp.FirstName && contact.LastName == temp.LastName && contact.Company == temp.Company)
                            {
                                contacts1.Remove(contact);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
                def.Complete();
            }
        }

        private void BaseExample2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // We don't want to show the Move icon
            e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = false;
        }
    }

    // C# code-behind

    // The data template is defined to display a Contact object (class definition shown below), and the text
    // displayed is bound to the Contact object's Name attribute.

    public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public string Company { get; private set; }
        public string Name => FirstName + " " + LastName;

        public static string ContactsPath => $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\Assets\Contacts.txt";

        public Contact(string firstName, string lastName, string company)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Company = company;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

        #region Public Methods
        public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
        {
            string contactsPath = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\Assets\Contacts.txt";
            Uri contactsUri = new Uri(contactsPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            Uri _contactsUri = new Uri(ContactsPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(contactsPath);
            IList<string> lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);

            ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i += 3)
            {
                contacts.Add(new Contact(lines[i], lines[i + 1], lines[i + 2]));
            }

            return contacts;
        }

        // To create a collection of grouped items, create a query that groups
        // an existing list, or returns a grouped collection from a database.
        // The following method is used to create the ItemsSource for our CollectionViewSource:

        public static async Task<ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>> GetContactsGroupedAsync()
        {
            // Grab Contact objects from pre-existing list (list is returned from function GetContactsAsync())
            var query = from item in await GetContactsAsync()

                            // Group the items returned from the query, sort and select the ones you want to keep
                        group item by item.LastName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() into g
                        orderby g.Key

                        // GroupInfoList is a simple custom class that has an IEnumerable type attribute, and
                        // a key attribute. The IGrouping-typed variable g now holds the Contact objects,
                        // and these objects will be used to create a new GroupInfoList object.
                        select new GroupInfoList(g) { Key = g.Key };

            return new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>(query);
        }

        #endregion

    }

    // GroupInfoList class definition:
    public class GroupInfoList : List<object>
    {
        public GroupInfoList(IEnumerable<object> items) : base(items)
        {
        }
        public object Key { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the debugger is configured to break on at least every CLR exception (exception settings). Now the application will halt when an exception is thrown during the debugger session.

Comment: It feels like you posted too much code. Try to simplify and reduce the code. Only post the minimal necessary code that is required to reproduce the behavior. While reducing and simplifying the code to produce the minimal example, you may find the issue yourself.

Comment: Check the output window in Visual Studio if there is any error.

Comment: The `await` in the drop handler seems suspicious. Try it without that. Usually the drag/drop mechanism in these frameworks halts the message processing during a drop. That may prevent any kind of resume operation.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop is not on the list of supported functionality in and preview 0.5
I think they fixed a few serious bugs in 0.5.
Try again when 0.8 is released.

Remember you are one of the earlierst birds when you use WinUI3 now. You don't get only the worm but also the mud.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the posted code, I think you changed `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` or (not xor) removed the default reference `MainWindow` in order to make your app. If your app does not start and does not reach any break point in your Page, it's because it is not in the "execution chain" which starts with App.xaml.

App.xaml calls the MainWindow class (View):

```
<Application x:Class="MyProject.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"> <!-- reference here-->
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then, from `MainWindow` (.xaml and .xaml.cs) you should have your Page referenced.